# React - Is it fine to have large static/assets folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am ML pro getting up to speed on React/frontend.

If I have alot of images for a lot pages for a React application, can I put all those images in a static/assets folder?

Is that going to slow down the application or are the static images only going to affect the application when the component with the images are rendered?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not going to slow it down at all, just having a bunch of static assets sitting on the server has no effect on the performance client side. Only when those assets are being fetched by the client does performance start to matter, but again only for the **specific** assets being fetched, the others are irrelevant

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for that. I appreciate the help. So the static/assets folder is not loaded to the client side when the application is first rendered on the client side? The static/assets folder stays on the server side and is only used when the frontend tries to load those images? Thanks for the help and feel free to expand more. Thanks Jay.

Comment: Usually when we talk about performance we mean performance of JS runtime, or more intuitively, the responsiveness of the app in terms of user experience. Fact is, static assets are handled by other background process of the browser, they don’t even effect the JS runtime. So no, loading images will not influence app

Comment: If you just put those images in the static folder, then they just sit there waiting to be served. Unless you app/webpage load these images, they’re just bits on the disk, they’re not even loaded in the memory, let alone impacting performance. And plus, performance impact of loaded resources are also isolated from the JS engine, so just don’t worry about it.

Comment: Thank you hackape. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No the browser doesn't load all the static assets of a site, imagine how slow sites would be!! Only once they're specifically requested do they get sent from the server to the client

Comment: Nice. Thanks Jay! Appreciate your help.